# Prevent Bootstrap from being responsive in certain screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to stop from changing the layout at a given resolution, say `768px` wide.

Is there a way to set that across the board in my app?

Comment: Give your content container max width of 768px and it won't expand. What's the problem?

Comment: I think I would actually use the min-width attribute to prevent it from shrinking to < 768px.  I also want it to be 'zoomed out' so it looks like it would on a screen larger than 768px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your container a min-width of whatever amount you want.

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px){
    body {
        min-width: 960px;
    }
}
```